# Cassandra Connection using groovy script when rpc_address is not set as 0.0.0.0

Tags: groovy, cassandra

I need to access cassandra from SOUPUI

I have used the below script

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

def rs;


//create cluster for cassandra
Cluster cluster = new Cluster.Builder().addContactPoint("xxxx").withCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx").withPort(9042).build();

//get seesionm from cassandra claster
session = cluster.connect();



//log.info(rs)
```

The issue i could see is

`/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml` `rpc_address` is not configured to `0.0.0.0` for security reason. It has one IP.

Please suggest me a way to connect to cassandra when `rpc_address` and broadcast_address is different IP

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you configure Cassandra with:

```
listen_address: public_ip
rpc_address: private_ip
```

But if you have a single NIC machine, you set both to the same IP.

You only need to configure `broadcast_address` if you have a multi-region cluster. I've answered a similar question previously. For details, see this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/6019/. Cheers!